# Python Codes using the pyautogui library not working. This if else block is not working, what error am I doing?

Tags: python, image, if-statement, mouse, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import python_imagesearch
from python_imagesearch import imagesearch
from time import sleep

donme1 = (-1, 300) 
donme2 = (300, 300)  

pos = imagesearch.imagesearch('tra.png', 0.7)
print(pos)

def donuszamani():
    pyautogui.moveTo(donme1)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(donme2)
    time.sleep(1)

def sagisin():
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.mouseDown(button='right')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.mouseUp(button='right')
    time.sleep(1)

def solisin():
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
    time.sleep(1)

if pos:
    if pos[0] != -1:
        print("position : ", pos[0], pos[1])
        pyautogui.moveTo(pos[0]+93, pos[1]+90)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pyautogui.mouseUp()
        sagisin()
        print("Congratulations 1")
    else:
        donuszamani()
        print()
else:
    donuszamani()
    if pos[0] != -1:
        print("position : ", pos[0], pos[1])
        pyautogui.moveTo(pos[0]+93, pos[1]+90)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        pyautogui.mouseUp()
        sagisin()
        print("Congratulations")
    else:
        ("Nope")
```

This is how I wrote my Python Codes using the pyautogui library. I'm writing a simple bot. In these codes, the coding ends after the first if else block. He sees the photo when I show him and continues, but when he does not see the photo, I say turn back, but after he returns once, it does not continue. I think I've come up with a dysfunctional code. How do i fix this.

Comment: _but after he returns once, it does not continue_ What exactly do you mean by "continue"?  That if/else block happens once, and then the program ends.  There is no loop.

Comment: Also, `("Nope")` won't do anything.  Did you mean to have a `print()` statement?

Comment: So I don't want it to end before I find the photo. When he returns 2-3 times, he will definitely find it, but the code ends before he returns.

Comment: if's aren't loops